# Android development: How to find out which applications are currently accessing the internet?

Tags: android

Is there any method that can help me track internet usage by application? I need to find out which app is using Internet at the moment.

I've managed to get all applications with INTERNET permission but I don't know how to get only those applications that are connected to internet.

```
for(int i=0; i<applications.size(); i++){
        ApplicationInfo info = applications.get(i);
        if(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED==packageManager.checkPermission(Manifest.permission.INTERNET, info.packageName)){
            netApplications.add(info);      
        }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no way of determining "which app is using Internet at the moment".

However, using [`TrafficStats`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html), you can determine which apps are using the Internet over a period of time. [Here is a sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtuning/tree/master/TrafficMonitor) showing the use of `TrafficStats` for this purpose.

Also, on Android 4.0+, the Settings application can show you bandwidth consumption, but typically over a significant period of time.

Comment: Hm ... Then it could be possible but not so accurate. TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(appUid); I could take number of bytes two times. First time at the beggining and then put some delay and get new values. If numbers are different then app is probably using Internet. What do you think?

Comment: @ZdravkoVajudin: "First time at the beggining and then put some delay and get new values. If numbers are different then app is probably using Internet." -- correct.